# Record Centre hierarchy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, records-center

I want to create a record centre for my sharepoint 2019.  I also have a document centre.  I want to use the same fileplan for both.  In the document centre, I've created subsites (as document centres) with document libraries and folders.
What type of sub sites should I use to create in my Record centre?

Comment: This should be determined according to your needs. You can refer to this article to see if it can help.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-the-records-center-bae6ca5a-7b19-40e0-b433-e3613a747c2c

Comment: Thank you Amy. I was contemplating about the type of subsites to use, but I think I got my answer